# mysql datetime formatted %m-%d-%Y throws an out of range error in rails form

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime, form-for, strftime

I have a mysql table with a field named 'expires' that is of type datetime

when I visit the rails edit page for this table, I want to display the expires date as "month/day/year"

In the view, edit.html.erb I have the following

```
<%= form_for @client, url: {action: "update"} do |f| %>
       ...
   <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :expires, "Expires"  %> 
        <%= f.text_field(:expires , :id => 'expires_on')  %> 
   </div>
```

and in the controller I have

```
def edit
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    @client.expires = @client.expires.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
end
```

however this throws an "argument out of range" error 
if I format it "%d/%m/%Y" I don't get the error

I'm guessing this has to do with the active record not allowing month first, but is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to use a formatted field, you can add a new "virtual" field to your model:

```
def expires_formatted
  expires.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
end

def expires_formatted=(val)
  expires = Date.strptime(val, "%m/%d/%Y")
end
```

and use `expires_formatted` instead of `expires`.

But I would recommend to use jQuery UI datepicker for editing date field. You can also read about date fields implementations from Ryan Bates [episode on RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars).